# Small lookup table vs if-else and performance

Tags: c, performance

I have few billon of record and their first character is used to identify an action to be taken. I have been asked to remove if else from code and to check performance. So I created a small lookup table with `char` as an array index and stored function pointers at those indices. Code is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int add_check, mod_check, del_check, strike_check;
void add(int rnum){
  add_check = add_check + rnum;
}
void modify(int rnum){
  mod_check = mod_check + rnum;
}
void delete(int rnum){
  del_check = del_check + rnum;
}
void strike (int rnum) {
  strike_check = strike_check + rnum;
}

int main(void){
  void (*action_fn[91])(int);
  memset (action_fn, 0, sizeof(action_fn));
  add_check = mod_check = del_check = strike_check = 0;
  action_fn['A'] = add;
  action_fn['M'] = modify;
  action_fn['D'] = delete;
  action_fn['S'] = strike;

  unsigned char msg[] = {
    'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'S','A', 'D', 'M','S', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D','D',
    'D', 'M','A','D', 'A', 'A', 'A','M','M','S','M','S','M', 'S','A','A',
    'D', 'M','M','M','S', 'A','D','M', 'A','S','M','D','D','D','D','A',
    'A','A','A', 'A', 'D', 'M', 'D', 'M', 'A', 'S','S','S','D', 'M','S' ,
    'A', 'A', 'A', 'D','D','D', 'A','D','M', 'A','M','D','D','D','D','A',
    'A','A','A', 'M','A','D', 'A', 'A', 'A','M','M','M','M', 'A','A','D',
    'M','M','M', 'A','M','D','A','A','A','A','M','M','D','D'
  };

  clock_t start;
  double elapsed_time;

  start = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(msg); i++ ){
    if (msg[i] == 'A'){
      add(1); 
    } else if (msg[i] == 'M') {
      modify(1);
    } else if (msg[i] == 'D'){
      delete(1);
    } else if (msg[i] == 'S'){
      strike(1);
    }
  }
  elapsed_time = (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("ElapsedTime-ifelse:%0.6f\n", elapsed_time);
  printf("add_check:%d mod_check:%d del_check:%d strike_check:%d\n",
      add_check, mod_check, del_check, strike_check);
  
  start = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < (int)sizeof(msg); i++ ){
    action_fn[msg[i]](1);
  }
  elapsed_time = (double)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf ("ElapsedTime-fp:%0.7f\n", elapsed_time);
  printf ("add_check:%d mod_check:%d del_check:%d"
        "strike_check :%d\n",
      add_check, mod_check, del_check, strike_check);
  
  return 0;
}
```

So I have following doubt since this simple test is not giving any clear results. Will this lookup table help in improving performance when number of records are really high and Add,Mod,Del and Strike is random? Or it will not help at all since there are limited conditions or lookup table will perform badly compared to if-else?

Comment: How about using a `switch` and letting the compiler worry about the implementation?

Comment: "*not giving any clear results*". Please share your results. Though I doubt you will get any meaningful performance characterisation with the tiny data set shown in the code.

Comment: The real question is how much time it takes to decide which function to call versus how much time the function itself takes. If the function itself is taking several microseconds, then trying to optimize the code that calls the function is pointless. It won't make a noticable difference in overall performance.

Comment: You know you could write something like 
`unsigned char msg[] = "ADM..."` instead of separate characters?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The compiler won't substitute the jump table with a lookup table

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There's nothing stopping it, but the situation doesn't come up often enough for anyone to bother writing a compiler that does so.

Comment: @kaylum : Yes you are right; with small set of data, all are showing equal results and at times the whichever is first performs bad. I tried using `srand` and rand % 109 but that I could not do cleanly.

Comment: As the other comments are alluding to you are probably focusing on the wrong thing. There are only four conditions so I doubt whether there will be any significant performance difference between the two approaches. If someone is telling you to make that change for performance reasons you should challenge them to prove that that part  needs optimising first. Otherwise it is a case of an attempt at premature or unnecessary optimisation.

Comment: Instead of building in your timing code, just run a profiler and feed it the billions of records you're talking about. You have definitely wasted your own time.

Comment: Does the functions `add`/`modify`/`delete`/etc. contain a code used in a real-world program or this just toy functions written for this example?

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Its somewhat identical to real-world operation but there are 2 more operations and if based counter.

Comment: Ok, if such operations are quite computationally basic and similar in all these functions, it may be better to use a branchless implementation to get ride of branch missprediction issues. This was why I asked this.

Comment: As other people pointed out, for the small number of `if`s the performance difference between two approaches is negligible. The performance profile of your program will be dominated by cache misses when accessing your records.